# What is the noun corresponding to verbose?

Tags: word-choice

Consider the following sentence.

> I am a verbose person.

What would be a good substitution for the adjective if one'd like to express the same thought using a noun?

> I am a person who likes *xxx*.

I'm thinking *verbosity* but it might be *verbality*, *verbing* or something like *verboseness* etc. Can't decide which is the best or if any suffice at all.

Comment: Have you tried looking in a dictionary?

Comment: @BillJ Is there a dictionary for adjective-to-noun correspondence? I usually look up synonyms and antonyms. But this particular conversion (and others of the kind, of course), I'm not aware of any tools for. Care to provide a link so I can use it for future references?

Comment: @Mari-LouA As you say, *verbosity* was the first thing on my mind. For some reason (that I can't explain, it's just a hunch) I got uncertain of its appropriateness. Maybe just worrying too much...

Comment: Most dictionaries give derivatives [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/verbose?fallbackFrom=british-grammar)

Comment: @BillJ Interesting. I've found [this link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbose) and since they listed multiple alternatives, I had the impression that they were automatically generated, hence not reliable.  And, at any rate, it makes me even more uncertain which one to pick. If any. What would you say is a proper answer to this specific case?

Comment: I'd use 'verbosity', but apparently 'verboseness' is an alternative. I can't recall ever hearing or seeing the latter alternant used, and it only registers a flicker on Google NGram: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbosity%2Cverboseness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbosity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverboseness%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbose) does not "automatically generate" related forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The noun corresponding to *verbose* is *verbosity*.

However, in my opinion, it does not fit well for your particular example because "I'm a person who likes verbosity"

a) sounds weird (at least to my ear)
b) can be understood as 'I like when someone else is verbose'.

So, for your example, "I'm a person who likes blathering a lot" would be a better substitution :)

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder if there's something instead of or in addition to your suggested alternative that better matches the formality or height of the terms *verbose, verbosity.*

Comment: @JimReynolds. Let's wait and see if someone comes up with something clever. Another idea just occurred to me: considering that _verbosity_ is usually seen as a negative quality, a phrase "I'm a person _prone to verbosity_" seems appropriate. Google gives a few occurrences of such an expression.

Comment: There's also *verboseness*, as listed by  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbose).

Comment: There's the wonderful word "prolixity" (which I so rarely get the chance to use in a sentence); however it is more negative than "verbosity".  If you want some fun, you can use the picturesque "logorrhea", which also gives you the chance to explain what it means.  More pompous: "grandiloquence", more *talky*: "loquacious", more indirect: "circumlocution" or "periphrasis" or "discursiveness".   Lots of options.